# Why isn't not (a and b) the same as not a and not b?

Tags: python, algorithm, boolean-logic

Why isn't `Not(a and b)` the same as `Not a and Not b`?

```
while i < len(array) - 1:
    if not array[i - 1] < array[i] and not array[i] > array[i + 1]:
        i += 1
        continue

while i < len(array) - 1:
isPeak = array[i - 1] < array[i] and array[i] > array[i + 1]
        if not isPeak:
            i += 1
            continue
```

I included the code that brought this up but why isn't `Not(a and b)` the same as `Not a and Not b`?

Comment: Because `not (a and b)` is logically not the same as `not a and not b`.

Comment: Please repeat [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.  Doing the initial internal investigation is *your* task.
This is the start of learning to debug.  See this [lovely debugging site](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for help.

Comment: Prompt: Write a function that takes in an array of integers and returns the length of the longest peak in the array. Must be strictly increasing before tip and decreasing after tip of peak, with a minimum of three integers required to form a peak. No repeating integers.

Comment: Google De Morgan's Laws.

Comment: The answer to your updated question is "because that's just how Boolean logic works". As said, see for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws

Comment: `not (a and b) == not a or not b` and `not a and not b == not (a or b)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because they're not logically equivalent. You can work it out for yourself with a truth table:

| A | B | not A | not B | not A and not B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| F | F | T | T | T |
| F | T | T | F | F |
| T | F | F | T | F |
| T | T | F | F | F |

| A | B | A and B | not (A and B) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| F | F | F | T |
| F | T | F | T |
| T | F | F | T |
| T | T | T | F |

If you look at [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) there's a simple transformation available; when you distribute the `not` into the parentheses, you flip from `and` to `or` (and vice-versa), so `not (A and B)` is equivalent to `not A or not B`; if you make a truth table for that, you'll find they match perfectly. Similarly, pulling out the `not` from `not A and not B` produces `not (A or B)`, and again, the truth table matches.

Comment: @VLAZ: Thanks for the improved formatting, didn't realize [they'd introduced tables to Markdown](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/356997/322040).